# Why this reator code with block inside Flux.create couldn't work?

Tags: project-reactor, watchservice

I've tried to use a watchService as a Flux generator and it couldn't work, and I also tried some simple block like Thread.sleep in the Flux.create method and it could work. 
I wonder why and what's the difference between these situations?

Code which could work,

```
    @Test
    public void createBlockSleepTest() throws InterruptedException {
        Flux.create(sink->{
            while (true) {
                try {
                    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
                        sink.next(num++);
                    Thread.sleep(5000L);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).log().subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel(),false).log()
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
        Thread.sleep(100000L);
    }
```

Code which couldn't work,

```
    @Test
    public void createBlockTest() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        WatchService watchService = fileSystem.newWatchService();
        Path testPath = fileSystem.getPath("C:/testing");
        Files.createDirectories(testPath);
        WatchKey register = testPath.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE,StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);
        Files.write(testPath.resolve("test1.txt"),"hello".getBytes());
        Thread.sleep(5000L);
        Flux.create(sink->{
            while (true) {
                try {
                    WatchKey key = watchService.take();
                    System.out.println("-----------------"+key);
                    for(WatchEvent event:key.pollEvents()){
                        sink.next(event.context());
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(5000L);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).log().subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel(),false).log()
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
        Files.write(testPath.resolve("test2.txt"),"hello".getBytes());
        Thread.sleep(5000L);
        Files.write(testPath.resolve("test3.txt"),"hello".getBytes());
        Thread.sleep(10000L);
    }
```

I've noticed in the reactor's reference there is a notice for blocking in the create method. But why Thread.sleep works?

`create` **doesn’t parallelize your code nor does it make it asynchronous**, even
though it *can* be used with asynchronous APIs. If you block within the `create` lambda,
you expose yourself to deadlocks and similar side effects. Even with the use of `subscribeOn`,
there’s the caveat that a long-blocking `create` lambda (such as an infinite loop calling
`sink.next(t)`) can lock the pipeline: the requests would never be performed due to the
loop starving the same thread they are supposed to run from. Use the `subscribeOn(Scheduler, false)`
variant: `requestOnSeparateThread = false` will use the `Scheduler` thread for the `create`
and still let data flow by performing `request` in the original thread.

Could anyone solve my puzzle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Thread.sleep(5000L)` will only block for 5s, so the `create` will move on after that delay, whereas `WatchService#take` blocks indefinitely unless a new `WatchKey` registers (in this case a new file). Since the code that creates files is after the `create`, there is a deadlock situation.

Comment: Other than sleep, is there any common case in java can be defined as "defined" blocks? Or is it about the blocking time? (Nice to meet you. Saw your videos in youtude, helps a lot.)

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed by changing

```
            while (true) {
            try {
                WatchKey key = watchService.take();
                System.out.println("-----------------"+key);
                for(WatchEvent event:key.pollEvents()){
                    sink.next(event.context());
                }
                Thread.sleep(5000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

to

```
            while (true) {
            try {
                WatchKey key = watchService.take();
                System.out.println("-----------------"+key);
                for(WatchEvent event:key.pollEvents()){
                    sink.next(event.context());
                }
                key.reset();
                Thread.sleep(5000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```